# Understanding coffescript functions scope and return object kind - while trying to get JSON

Tags: coffeescript

I would like to have some function `getTagsDict()` visible to broder scope, which will be responsible for some GET request to the server and returning dictionary, which can be then easily accesed in loop like:

`for k,v of getTagsDict()`

For now below code returns some js crap (or at least for js-newbie): https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQPQw.png

```
getTagsDict = () ->
    $.get '/notifications/ajax_avalaible_search_tags/', (data) ->
        data
$ ->
    $('#ajax_search_input').on 'keyup', (e) ->
        for k,v of getTagsDict()
            console.log "#{k} and #{v}"
```

But when doing GET just inside the calling method everything works well:

```
$ ->
    $('#ajax_search_input').on 'keyup', (e) ->
        $.get '/notifications/ajax_avalaible_search_tags/', (data) ->
            for k,v of data
                console.log "#{k} and #{v}"
```

**QUESTION:** How should I use coffee's functions to be globaly and to be utilized as described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue was to build `getTagsDict` as function with asynchronus ajax call. It can look for example like this:

```
getTagsDict = ->

  strReturn = ""

  jQuery.ajax
    async: false
    url: "/notifications/ajax_avalaible_search_tags/"
    success: (data) ->
      strReturn = data

  strReturn
```